# Lost mirror distro Ubuntu 16.04.03

Tags: mirrors

Struggling with Ubuntu for a while now. Will be trying to do a manual upgrade of Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.03 without USB or CD.

Just donated to the upgraded version (16.04.03);

Paused the download and shut down the computer;

Rebooted later, and the partial download was missing from the download folder.

I tweaked a couple of the donation "slide bars" before donating.

Is it possible to get the same download without donating again?

Comment: You do not have to donate, but kudos for doing so. Not sure why struggle.

Comment: New to it all. Something went wrong in my initial installation. Was unable to get a clear understanding from my searches of what to do. Hence struggling, and decided on full system restore; Also, on the download page you get a download of whatever level that is already set, but, if you donate, you can tweak those slide bars for extra things that add up to $625. $625 is a nice sum to simply be told that you do not have to donate, had I paid that much. Need answers as to how to go about downloading Ubuntu 16.04.03 with the extras I donated too.

Comment: Can't find customer service, tech support. Payment institution can't help accept with invoice number, but, send it to whom? Where?